# Why does this python code work?

Tags: python, module, visibility, global

I have written a simple python module, it has this code:

```
_log = logging.getLogger("mymodule")
_started = False

def set_log_level(level):
    _log.setLevel(level)
    if not _started:
        _hdlr = logging.FileHandler('mymodule.log')
```

When I call `set_log_level()` program fails because symbol `_started` is not found. It is normal because `global _started` is missing in the method. But my question is: symbol `_log` has the same visibility as `_started`, so why does this symbol can be found?

Comment: If I run this under Python 2.7.1, I get no errors. I added a line `set_log_level(3)`.

Comment: It shouldn't fail. Is that all code?

Comment: Is that your whole code? Do you have anything like `_started = True` in the code you're actually running? The presence of an assignment in a Python function will shadow the global, even if the assignment appears *after* the first use.

Comment: @GregHewgill was right! I miss those line in the snippet. This line converts _started into local variable and that's why `global _started` is required.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your program fails for the reason you think. There's no need to use the `global` declaration within a function unless you actually modify that variable. (Otherwise, you'd need to use global for every access of something in that namespace, even calling other functions.)

I'm not sure what actually happens when you run your program - perhaps you could provide a traceback or description of the problem.